# Gnuplot wrong ploth with xdata time

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Hi i have a lite problem I cant genrate correct plot with time and many points ,When i try plot groups data ...

My example input data in file bps.sh

```
17/03/17 17:36:30;20411.000
17/03/17 17:36:40;23928.000
17/03/17 17:36:56;1914.000
17/03/17 17:37:07;23375.000
17/03/17 17:37:17;23712.000
17/03/17 17:37:28;22587.000
17/03/17 17:37:38;23505.000
17/03/17 17:37:49;21050.000
17/03/17 17:38:00;13137.000
17/03/17 17:38:10;20664.000
```

My script

```
set title "Analysing speed WAN\nwith date curl -L -w google.com "
unset multiplot
set xdata time
set style data dots
#set style fill solid 1.0
set datafile separator ";"
set xlabel "Date\nTime"
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y %H%M%S"
set format x "%H\n%d/%m"
#set yrange [ 0 : ]
set xdata time
set autoscale  xy
set ylabel "Speeed \nbytes/s"
set grid
set term png size 1440,720
set output "speedtest.png"
plot 'bps.sh' using 1:2 t 'bytes/s' w points
```

When i generate using xdata time i have this output :
[image: X time Y bps second column]
Data look like in groups ...

But when i use more simple data without  time, only second column in  file .

```
cat bps.sh| awk 'FS=";" {print $2}' > dot && gnuplot -persist <(echo -n "plot 'dot'  with points")
```

i have that effect 
[image: More simple plot without time on x axis]

How to create no group  data char with data information on x axis .

Answer (score 1):

In the first plot, data is rounded to "whole hours". This is because you specify the input format as

```
set timefmt "%d/%m/%y %H%M%S"
```

but the actual data is `"%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`.

Without the `:`s, Gnuplot parsed only hours and ignored the rest (minutes/seconds), thus the data points were effectively grouped into bins of size 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks , i don't see my mistake  . now its working great :)